# How to switch Microsoft accounts with Python Script

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I want to switch (sign-out/sign-in) Microsoft accounts preferably on Edge.
I'm looking for a way to automatically todo this action in a python script by being able to give which account to switch to.

Is there a way to perform this action in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution after some research. Selenium in python can work to help automate login and log out for any website.

Links to Site: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do so inside the web browser, you can use something like pyautogui in order to create a macro for auto sign in. If you do go that route, my suggestion would be making a macro recorder which can take your actions (clicking sign out, clicking login in, et) and play it back. Then you can use pyautogui.write() to input login credentials.

Comment: Does this work if the python script runs on vscode outside the browser?

Comment: pyautogui uses your actual cursor and keyboard. As long as the script is run on your machine and you have edge open and focused (so not minimized), it should work

Comment: @Xanthan (forgot to mention in previous comment)